# Communicate Stack Navigation with Drawer Navigation to login

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make an application where navigation is, if the user has not logged in then I have a stack navigation with 3 screens (Welcome, Login, Register).
If I already log in then I change navigation and now I use a drawer navigation to be able to show the drawer at all times with a close session button.
The decision to use one navigation or another is taken by App.js through its state.
The problem is that since navigation I cannot modify the state of app.js so that it is rendered again and take the corresponding action.

Before it was a navigation drawer that inside it composes a navigation of stack.
The problem was that the drawer had to show a QR code that consumed it from an API. The QR code was not shown the first time the session was started because the drawer had already been rendered since the application started. Therefore, I was forced to change the logic in which I was doing things.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading:true,
      isLogged:false
    }
  }

  render(){
    let loading = this.state.loading;
    let logged = this.state.isLogged;
    if(loading != false){
      return(<Bienvenida />)
    }else{
      if(logged){
        return(<Navigation />)
      }else{
        return (<UserNavigation />)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, i would suggest using a `switchNavigator`.

A switchNavigator let you navigate trough screens like they were web pages, destroying the latest screen it had before.

The structure would be something like:

```
createSwitchNavigator({
    StackNav: {
        screen: stackNav,
    },
    DrawerNav: {
        screen: drawerNav
     }
})
```

Your stack would handle all the parts when the user is not logged. Then, when the user has logged in, you can pass from the stack to the drawer.

Same for a later logout, from the drawer you navigate to the stack

For more infos: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html